# Adjacent JSX elements must be wrapped (tried everything)

Tags: reactjs

I know there is a lot of anwsers to this question but I tried to wrap my code with  react fragment but i still get the same error so i dunno where i should do it.

Here's my code

```
import React, { Component, Fragment } from 'react';
return (
  <React.Fragment>
    <section className='section'>
      {profileStore.pdfData ? (
        <Modal />
      ) : ''}
      <div className='neuralia-background' />
      {profileStore.company ? (
        <div className='container'>
          <div className='columns'>
            <div className='h-100 container is-vertical column is-half'>
              <div className='box'>
                <div className='columns'>
                  <div className='column is-half has-text-centered is-flex jst-space drc-column'>
                    <img alt='' src={profileStore.company.quote_logo} />
                    <h2 className='is-size-6 mb-1'>OFFRE DE PRIX</h2>
                  </div>
                  <div className='column is-half has-text-centered is-flex jst-space drc-column'>
                    <textarea
                      className='has-background-white-ter is-medium no-border is-shadowless textarea has-fixed-size mb-1'
                      type='text'
                      value={leftTextarea}
                      onChange={e => this.onTypeLeftTextarea(e)}
                    />
                    <input
                      className='input is-medium has-background-white-ter no-border is-shadowless'
                      type='text'
                      value={addressInput}
                      onChange={e => this.onTypeAddressInput(e)}
                    />
                  </div>
                </div>
                <div className='columns'>
                  <div className='column is-flex w-100 is-size-7'>
                    {profileStore.company.quote_notes}
                  </div>
                </div>
                {leftSideProduct.length ? leftSideProduct.map(c => (
                  <div className='columns' key={c.product_id}>
                    <div className='column is-4 is-flex jst-cnt alg-cnt has-text-centered'>
                      <h2 className='is-uppercase'>{c.product_name}</h2>
                    </div>
                    <div className='column is-6 is-flex alg-cnt has-text-centered'>
                      <input
                        className='input has-text-centered is-medium has-background-white-ter no-border is-shadowless'
                        type='text'
                        placeholder='ex: 100, 1000, 10000'
                        value={c.quantity}
                        onChange={e => this.onTypeQuantity(e, c)}
                      />
                    </div>
                    <div className='column is-2 is-flex jst-cnt alg-cnt'>
                      <div
                        role='button'
                        tabIndex='0'
                        onKeyDown={this.onDeleteProduct.bind(this, c)}
                        onClick={this.onDeleteProduct.bind(this, c)}
                      >
                        <img
                          width='30'
                          alt=''
                          src={require('~/assets/img/trash.svg')}
                        />
                      </div>
                    </div>
                  </div>
                )) : ''
                }
                {profileStore.estimations
                  && (
                    <div className='columns'>
                      <div className='column is-4 has-text-centered'>
                        <h2>Prix Hors Taxes</h2>
                        <p>Version v1</p>
                      </div>
                      <div className='column is-6 is-flex alg-cnt has-text-centered'>
                        <input
                          className='input has-text-centered is-medium has-background-white-ter no-border is-shadowless'
                          type='text'
                          value={profileStore.estimations.amount}
                          onChange={e => this.onTypePrice(e)}
                        />
                      </div>
                      <div className='column is-flex jst-cnt alg-cnt is-2 has-text-centered'>
                        <p>{profileStore.estimations.currency}</p>
                      </div>
                    </div>
                  )
                }
                <div className='columns'>
                  <div className='column w-100 is-size-7 is-flex'>
                    {profileStore.company.quote_footer}
                  </div>
                </div>
              </div>
            </div>
            {profileStore.catalogs.length ? (
              <div className='h-100 container is-vertical column is-half'>
                <div className='box'>
                  {showPPhares ? (
                    <div className='has-text-centered has-text-grey-darker subtitle'>Produits phares</div>
                    <div className='buttons has-text-white is-centered border'>
                      { profileStore.recommendations.length
                        && profileStore.recommendations.map(c => (
                          <button
                            type='button'
                            className='button products is-info is-uppercase animated'
                            key={c.product_id}
                            onClick={this.onClickProduct.bind(this, c)}
                          >
                            {c.product_name}
                          </button>
                        ))
                      }
                    </div>
                  ) : ''}
                  <div>
                    <div className='has-text-centered has-text-grey-darker subtitle'>Produits Associés</div>
                    <div className='buttons has-text-white is-centered border'>
                      { profileStore.mostAssociated.length
                        && profileStore.mostAssociated.map(c => (
                          <button
                            type='button'
                            className='button products is-info is-uppercase animated'
                            key={c.product_id}
                            onClick={this.onClickProduct.bind(this, c)}
                          >
                            {c.product_name}
                          </button>
                        ))
                      }
                    </div>
                    </div>


                  <div className='tile is-child is-12 mt-1'>
                    <p className='has-text-centered has-text-grey-darker subtitle'>Produits spécifiques</p>
                    {profileStore.catalogs2D.length ? (
                      <div className='buttons has-text-white is-centered border'>
                        {profileStore.catalogs2D[activePage - 1].length
                          && profileStore.catalogs2D[activePage - 1].map(p => (p.show ? (
                            <button
                              type='button'
                              className='button products is-info is-uppercase animated'
                              key={p.product_id}
                              onClick={this.onClickProduct.bind(this, p)}
                            >
                              {p.product_name}
                            </button>
                          ) : ''))}
                      </div>
                    ) : ''}
                    {profileStore.catalogs2D.length && profileStore.catalogs2D.length > 1 ? (
                      <div className='buttons are-small m-a mb-1 mt-1 is-centered w-100'>
                        <button className='button is-primary is-marginless' type='button' onClick={this.nextPage.bind(this, 'prev')}>Prev</button>
                        <span className='tag is-light ml-1 mr-1'>{activePage}</span>
                        <button className='button is-primary is-marginless' type='button' onClick={this.nextPage.bind(this, 'next')}>Next</button>
                      </div>
                    ) : ''}
                    <input
                      className='input has-text-centered is-medium has-background-white-ter no-border is-shadowless'
                      type='text'
                      placeholder='ex: brochure double'
                      value={searchInput}
                      onChange={e => this.onSearchProduct(e)}
                    />
                  </div>
                </div>
                <div className='buttons has-text-white are-medium is-centered'>
                  <button type='submit' onClick={this.onGetPrice.bind(this)} className={`button is-success is-uppercase ${leftSideProduct.length ? '' : 'is-hidden'}`}>Calculer le prix</button>
                  <button type='submit' onClick={this.onVisualizer.bind(this)} className={`button is-purple has-text-white no-border is-uppercase ${profileStore.estimations && profileStore.estimations.amount > 0 ? '' : 'is-hidden'}`}>Previsualiser</button>
                  <button type='submit' onClick={this.onDeleteProduct.bind(this, 'all')} className={`button is-dark is-uppercase ${leftSideProduct.length ? '' : 'is-hidden'}`}>Retour</button>
                </div>
                {profileStore.estimations && profileStore.estimations.amount > 0 ? <SendEmail leftTextarea={leftTextarea} addressInput={addressInput} leftSideProduct={leftSideProduct} /> : ''}
              </div>
            ) : ''}
          </div>
        </div>
      ) : ''}
    </section>
  </React.Fragment>
```

Here's my error message:

Adjacent JSX elements must be wrapped in an enclosing tag. Did you want a JSX fragment <>...? (260:22)

Comment: Can you show  the code that doesn't work? It can be pretty silly, but did you also import `Fragment` from React to be able to use it? Also do you use the right version of react that supports Fragments?

Comment: what did you try to wrap with Fragment? did you try to wrap the two divs inside showPPhares  ?

Comment: I don't see `<>` and `</>` anywhere in that code.

Comment: The full of the render function would be useful. The idea is quite simple, any render has to have just one main element. If this is not the case, you either wrap it in `Fragment` or `<>`

Comment: You miss many closing tags for div's, you have two conditional operators, but you provide fallback only for one, the entire code illegible and chaotic. You are also using dive where could be replaced by span (with Produits phares).
Try co clean up code, extract map do different function. Try to make every conditional render as separated functional component. General reason of your failure is missing closing tags, else statements in conditional rendering because of spaghetti code.

Comment: @Bartosz was not the entire code and agree it's a spaghetti code that I did not write I try to improve it and fix it a bit but I'm not a react dev at the first place so i try to fix it piece by piece

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You are using ternary operator and when your condition equal to false you receive `''` and this is not a DOM element.
For fix it just wrap the second element. For example:

```
      {profileStore.catalogs.length ? (
        <div className='h-100 container is-vertical column is-half'>
          <div className='box'>
            {showPPhares ? (
              <div className='has-text-centered has-text-grey-darker subtitle'>Produits phares</div>
              <div className='buttons has-text-white is-centered border'>
                { profileStore.recommendations.length
                  && profileStore.recommendations.map(c => (
                    <button
                      type='button'
                      className='button products is-info is-uppercase animated'
                      key={c.product_id}
                      onClick={this.onClickProduct.bind(this, c)}
                    >
                      {c.product_name}
                    </button>
                  ))
                }
              </div>
            ) : <div>''<div>}
          //... other your code
```

Or in another way:

```
    <div>
     {profileStore.catalogs.length ? (
        <div className='h-100 container is-vertical column is-half'>
          <div className='box'>
            {showPPhares ? (
              <div className='has-text-centered has-text-grey-darker subtitle'>Produits phares</div>
              <div className='buttons has-text-white is-centered border'>
                { profileStore.recommendations.length
                  && profileStore.recommendations.map(c => (
                    <button
                      type='button'
                      className='button products is-info is-uppercase animated'
                      key={c.product_id}
                      onClick={this.onClickProduct.bind(this, c)}
                    >
                      {c.product_name}
                    </button>
                  ))
                }
              </div>
            ) : ''}
       //... other your code
     </div>
```

Comment: thank u very much the second piece of code did the trick in this spagh code :D